# How to display Monthly Active users (MAU)?

Tags: facebook

Hey there,
I want to fetch / display the MAU of a specific Facebook App. Is this possible or can this be done with a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with either the FQL or Graph API. To do it with the graph you will want to make the following call:

https://graph.facebook.com/your_app_id/insights

This will return you a json object. You will want to look for the insight called "application_active_users" for the period month.

You can find more about insights [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights) and [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights).

Comment: I had some problems getting a up to date value. The method you described seem to provide only historical data. I found also this solution best: http://stuff24.de/blog/monthly-active-users-facebook-fql/